# UIPickerView is not being dragged onto header file

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uipickerview

I keep trying to use CTRL-Drag from the uipickerview to the ViewController.h but its not creating the object definition in the header file. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your xib/storyboard you have set the correct class in the identity inspector.  From the drop-down menu, choose the correct subclass that you have created for your view.

[image: XCode Identity Inspector]

Comment: @ Jeff Wolski The UIPickerView is set for the right class and the view is set to UIView. This is in a tabbed storyboard so do I need to make multiple viewcontrollers for each tabbed view?

Comment: @user2423436 Yes, each tab should have it's own view controller.  It's not absolutely necessary for each tab to be it's own unique subclass of `UIViewController`, but it is very common and useful to do so.

Comment: Could that be the reason why its not dragging over, because its still not working.

Comment: Could be.  Depends on the specifics of your setup.

Comment: I'm using storyboard with ARC. I have a tab view connected to 5 other views. I'm adding a uipickerview to the 2nd view and another uipickerview to the 3rd view and I am not able to drag either one to the ViewController.h